# Nestjs / GraphQL - Playground Returns Null Error For Query. My Resolvers?

Tags: graphql, nestjs

Playground in my browser shows the Nestjs created schema nicely but queries are returning `null`.  Is there something wrong with my code?

```
"errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.getUsers.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
    }
```

This means no data found.

schema.graphql:

```
type UsersGQL {
    User_id: ID!
    first_name: String!
    last_name: String!
    main_skill_title: String!
    user_name: String!
    ....
}

type Query {
    getUser(user_id: ID!): UsersGQL!
    getUsers: [UsersGQL!]!
}
```

Compiles in Nestjs with GraphQL to graphql.schema.ts

```
export class UsersGQL {
    user_id: string;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    main_skill_title: string;
    user_name: string;
    ...
}

export abstract class IQuery {
    abstract getUser(user_id: string): UsersGQL | Promise<UsersGQL>;

    abstract getUsers(): UsersGQL[] | Promise<UsersGQL[]>;

    abstract temp__(): boolean | Promise<boolean>;
}
```

users.resolvers.ts

```
import { Query, Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

import { UsersGQL } from '../graphql.schema';
// import { UsersDTO } from './users.dto';


@Resolver('UsersGQL')
export class UsersResolvers {
  constructor(
    private readonly userService: UsersService
  ) {}

  @Query()
  async getUsers() {
    return await this.userService.findAll();
  }
}
```

The service works fine for my Nestjs REST API's.  The db is Postgres.

users.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository, getManager, getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { Members } from './members.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {

  private entityManager = getManager();

  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Users)
    private readonly usersRepository: Repository<Users>
  ) {}

  async findAll(): Promise<Users[]> {
    return await this.usersRepository.find();
  }
}
```

Playground query:

```
{
  getUsers {
    first_name
    last_name
  }
}
```

The error returned in Playground:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.getUsers.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "getUsers"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
             ...
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

Edit - added users.module.ts, app.module.ts and ormconfig.json.  This whole module is lazy loaded.  REST and GraphQL are side by side in the module.  I also separated REST and GQL components.

users.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

// REST
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { UsersController } from './users.controller';
import { Users } from './users.entity';

// GraphQL
import { UsersResolvers } from './users.resolvers';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([
      Users
      ]),
  ],
  providers: [
    UsersService,
    UsersResolvers
  ],
  controllers: [UsersController],
})

export class UsersModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { Module, NestModule, MiddlewareConsumer } from '@nestjs/common';

import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { join } from 'path';

import { LoggerMiddleware } from './logger.middleware';

import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';

import { UsersController } from './users/users.controller';



@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(),
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
      definitions: {
        path: join(process.cwd(), 'src/graphql.schema.ts'),
        outputAs: 'class',
      },
      debug: true,
    }),
    UsersModule
  ],
  controllers: [
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})

export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(LoggerMiddleware)
      .with('AppModule')
      .forRoutes(
        UsersController
    )};
}
```

ormconfig.json

```
...
"entities": [
    "src/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}",
    // "src/graphql.schema.ts"  This doesn't work.  Must use REST entity.
  ],
...
```

Comment: If I make the query nullable, remove the " ! ", then the query results are
{
  "data": {
    "getMembers": null
  }
}    This seems to mean that data isn't being returned through the service which is currently working fine for my REST api's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "solution" with this TypeORM architecture is to use the TypeORM entity.

users.resolvers.ts

```
import { Query, Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { Users } from './users.entity';  // Here

@Resolver('Users')
export class UsersResolvers {
  constructor(
    private readonly userService: UsersService
  ) {}

  @Query()
  async getUsers() {
    return await this.userService.findAll();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably imported `@Query` from `'@nestjs/common'` instead of `'@nestjs/graphql'`.

Make sure to have:

```
import { Query } from '@nestjs/graphql';
```

Comment: Thanks Kim but I have that right.  I found those other SO posts about this previously and was careful.  Besides, I just copied Kamil's work for his Github demo :-)

Comment: Ok, pity, that would have been an easy fix. ;-) Have you added a `console.log` to your service and made sure that it is called and does actually return an non-empty array?

Comment: There's also a typo in your service but that's probably just copy/paste: `userssRepository`

Comment: I did put console.log in my service and resolver but nothing happened in the IDE terminal window.

Comment: I have copied your code and tried it and for me it works. :-/ Can you remove `node_modules` and reinstall your dependencies and run `npm update`?

Comment: New node_modules and now change.  I just added my Playground query above, maybe that is the problem.  First time with this.

Comment: No, your query looks fine. Mhh... Can you reproduce your issue on codesandbox.io?

Comment: I'll try but I have to learn about code sandbox first.  Probably tomorrow because this is Woman's Day and my Russian wife wants to party :-)  I'm American.  So I haven't abandoned you if you don't hear from me for a while.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189701/discussion-between-kim-kern-and-preston).

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**

The fact that your schema is correctly exposed (and available via the playground) doesn't necessarily mean that all the corresponding modules and resolvers are integrated into your running Nest application.

---

I recently faced the same error and the reason was quite straightforward: I had forgotten to import the module including the resolver into the root module — usually `AppModule`.

So: are you sure you have all your `UserModule` module dependencies (and above all the `UserResolver`) imported and the `UsersModule` itself imported into your `AppModule`?

The trick here is that the GraphQL schema exposed by your server is directly generated from your source files. According to your Nest GraphQL configuration, it will compile all the `.graphql`, `.gql` files together ([schema first approach](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start#schema-first)) ; or the [type-graphql](https://typegraphql.ml) module, with Nest v6, will read all your source files looking for its decorators and generate the `schema.gql` ([code first approach](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/quick-start#code-first)). As a consequence, you can expose a correct schema even having no actual module resolving your request.

IMO, it's a buggy behaviour from the framework as it silently fails to resolve your schema without providing any explanation. The simple error message you get (`Cannot return null for non-nullable field Query.getUsers.`) is quite misleading as it hides the real failure, which is a **broken dependency**.

For more information, here is the related GitHub issue: https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/198

Comment: Thank you @MarsLevin!  Yes, members.module was imported into app.module as lazy loaded.  This is what made the REST code work well before I tried to setup GraphQL.  I've since refactored and separated out the GraphQL components to make it easier to troubleshoot.  Now I can get Nestjs to compile.  I get the error  ```No repository for "MembersGQL" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?```   I've added the refactored code and modules and part of the ormconfig.json to my original post.  Any ideas?

Comment: I got it to present the users from my Postgres DB in Playground but I don't like that it has to use the REST entity.  I want to remove all REST after I'm done converting to GraphQL.